# conversion batch to powerhsell autoreboot

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have to convert old batch files for installation of new PCS all the files went well until I had to remake the auto reboot and force a GPupdate.
I am stuck on this line of code

```
%windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v EnableLUA /t REG_SZ /d %~dp0AfterBoot.ps1 /f
```

I get the error code *The module '%windir%' could not be loaded*

I am rather new to scripting, I can manage in powershell but other types of scripting is a different world for me.

thank you in advance

Comment: environment variables in PoSh are reached via `$env:EnvVarName`, not the `%EnvVarName%` used by CMD/Bat code. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Batch scripting, variables are enclosed within percentage characters. `%windir%` is a system environment variable, and usually refers to `C:\Windows`. To set a Batch variable, percentages are not used. Oh, and the syntax is different in interactive and scripted versions too.

Powershell can access environment variables via `$env:` scope. Thus `$env:WINDIR` will return Windows' install directory.

Nowadays it's pretty uncommon to have Windows installation in some other location. Some 20+ years ago, on Windows NT 4.0 and Windows 2000 era, many NT installations were in `C:\WINNT` instead, so there was a need for a environment variable specifying the directory. The setup program actually asked for installation location. Windows 2008 supported alternate location via scripted installation only.